# XORing strings in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, xor

I want to write a program that encrypts a text using XOR-cipher. That's what I have for now:

```
-- XORres 2 strings
stringXor :: String -> String -> String
stringXor s t = map chr $ zipWith xor (map ord s) (map ord t)

-- encryption and decryption
encDec :: String -> String -> String
encDec text key = stringXor (take (length text) (cycle key)) text
```

But the output of `encDec "this is a test" "k"` is

```
  "\US\ETX\STX\CANK\STX\CANK\nK\US\SO\CAN\US"
```

while I was expecting something like `1f0302184b02184b0a4b1f0e181f4b`.

What could be the problem here? I've searched similar questions but that wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Well you xor the index number of the ASCII character. The result you then convert back to ascii, not as a hexadecimal string.

Comment: `chr` returns the character for the given ASCII value. It doesn't convert the number to hex. If you want a hexadecimal output, you will need to find something other than `chr`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the [**`chr :: Int -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:chr). This function converts an `Int` to the corresponding character, but *not* a hexadecimal representation of that number.

You can for example define a utility function with [**`intToDigit :: Int -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:intToDigit):

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

toHex2 :: Int -> String
toHex2 h = map intToDigit [d, m]
    where (d, m) = divMod h 16
```

Then we can implement the function as:

```
stringXor :: String -> String -> String
stringXor s t = concatMap toHex2 (zipWith xor (map ord s) (map ord t))
```

Or as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361341/xoring-strings-in-haskell/59361567?noredirect=1#comment104920154_59361567):

```
import Data.Function(on)

stringXor :: String -> String -> String
stringXor s t = concatMap toHex2 (zipWith (xor `on` ord) s t)
```

This then gives us:

```
Prelude Data.Char Data.Bits> encDec "this is a test" "k"
"1f0302184b02184b0a4b1f0e181f"
```

Note that you do not need to use `length` here, in fact it is safer *without* length, you can just use `cycle`:

```
encDec :: String -> String -> String
encDec text key = stringXor (cycle key) text
```

Comment: But now encDec is not nilpotent, right? And to its inverse I would have to use some 'chr . fromHex' on the encrypted text and then throw it all into 'encDec'? I'm asking because I am not sure if I understand the logic properly here

Comment: @arryn: Why not? `zipWith` stops from the moment one of the lists is exhausted. So if `text` is exhausted, regardless if `cycle key` is exhausted (it can not be exhausted), it will stop.

Comment: I meant that it's not nilpotent because of 'toHex' instead of 'chr'. So if I apply 'encDec' to previously encrypted text won't get the initial text, but only more encrypted one

Comment: @arryn: ah yes. In order to prevent that, you thus should make something that "decodes" a hex stream, instead of using `ord`. But then you can of course no longer use `"this is a test"` directly to encode data.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringXor s t = map chr $ zipWith xor (map ord s) (map ord t)
```

You map `chr` to the results of XOR. This results in characters for each ASCII value. To show the results as hexadecimal, you will need to find a different function to replace `chr` or write one yourself.

**Side note:** In cryptography, it is common to use Base64 notation to encode binary data instead of hex because it uses less characters (and therefore less memory or network bandwidth) to represent the same binary sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You *are* getting `1f0302184b02184b0a4b1f0e181f4b`:

```
> "\x1f\x03\x02\x18\x4b\x02\x18\x4b\x0a\x4b\x1f\x0e\x18\x1f\x4b"
"\US\ETX\STX\CANK\STX\CANK\nK\US\SO\CAN\USK"
```

...which is exactly the output you saw from `encDec` (up to what appears to be a simple copy-paste error in your expected output).

Comment: I'm getting the second line, which I don't know how to convert into the first line

Comment: @arryn What Daniel is saying is that the two strings are identical. E.g. `'\x1f'` and `'\US'` are two different representations of the same character.

Comment: @chi so is there a way to make the program show result in the '\x1f' way?

Comment: @arryn Before printing the result, you need to convert it to the right hex codes using something like Willem's `toHex` he posted above. This conversion is not used to return the result, only to print it in the wanted representation.

Comment: There's a difference between `"\x1f\x03...` and `"1f03..."`, though. The actual result is equivalent to the former, but not the latter.